# Using VBA's onboard sort function

Tags: vba, sorting, worksheet-function

I want to sort an array and since I am lazy I wanted to use the onboard sort function of EXCEL/VBA.
According to the official MS Office support worksheetfunctions.sort should also be working with arrays, see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sort-function-22f63bd0-ccc8-492f-953d-c20e8e44b86c).
Here is my first try.

```
Sub sorting()

Dim myArray1() As Double
Dim myArray2() As Double
ReDim myArray1(1 To 5)

myArray1(1) = 0.221157
myArray1(2) = -0.147981
myArray1(3) = -2.07119
myArray1(4) = 4.434685
myArray1(5) = -2.706056

myArray2 = WorksheetFunction.Sort(myArray1, 1, 1)

End Sub
```

This produces a type mismatch error, therefore I have adjusted my code to

```
Sub sorting()

Dim myArray1() As Variant
Dim myArray2() As Variant
ReDim myArray1(1 To 5)

myArray1(1) = 0.221157
myArray1(2) = -0.147981
myArray1(3) = -2.07119
myArray1(4) = 4.434685
myArray1(5) = -2.706056

myArray2 = WorksheetFunction.Sort(myArray1, 1, 1)

End Sub
```

The code runs without any error, but myArray2 is not sorted, it is just a copy of myArray1.

I am using:

Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2204 Build 16.0.15128.20128) 32-bit

Comment: I think it may mean array formula.

Comment: You mean like WorksheetFunction.sort(9,22,5,33), not an actual array as input argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is connected to the fourth function parameter...

It is `Optional`, but its makes sorting **by rows** if not used (`False`). Since you try sorting **a 1D array** not having any row, it does not sort anything.

You should use:

```
   myArray2 = WorksheetFunction.Sort(myArray1, 1, 1, True)
```

Such an array has only columns...

**Note**:
The array to be filtered must be declared `As Variant`, in the same way it is needed to be declared when it will be loaded from a range. The above function does not accept such an array declared `As Double`, `As Long`...

Comment: Your answer is right, thanks! But it only works if myArray1 and myArray2 are Variants, maybe you should add this. I tried it, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Zorg I am afraid, I cannot get you... It should work on any type of array elements. Please, try an example to make me understand what you mean. It is able to sort strings and numbers. What else would you like it to sort? `Variant` is the most general declaration... It accepts strings and numbers, anyhow.

Comment: this code does not work

 "Sub sorting()
    
    
    Dim myArray1() As Double
    Dim myArray2() As Double
    ReDim myArray1(1 To 5)
   
    myArray1(1) = 0.221157
    myArray1(2) = -0.147981
    myArray1(3) = -2.07119
    myArray1(4) = 4.434685
    myArray1(5) = -2.706056
    
    myArray2 = WorksheetFunction.Sort(myArray1, 1, 1, True)
End Sub"

Comment: This works
Sub sorting()
    
    
    Dim myArray1() As Variant
    Dim myArray2() As Variant
    ReDim myArray1(1 To 5)
   
    myArray1(1) = 0.221157
    myArray1(2) = -0.147981
    myArray1(3) = -2.07119
    myArray1(4) = 4.434685
    myArray1(5) = -2.706056
    
    myArray2 = WorksheetFunction.Sort(myArray1, 1, 1, True)
End Sub

Comment: I know that variant is just a generic data type, that is why I am surprised that it makes a difference. Both arrays being variants works, both being doubles does not work. I dont know why

Comment: @Zorg I am surprised, too. It works well on a sheet column, when it automatically converts the used data. It's strange... It is not mentioned in the function documentation. It probably is connected with the fact that you are able to place a range in an array, **only if you declare the respective array as `Variant`**... `arr = Range("A2:B5").Value` It practically is an extension of worksheet function use, I suppose.

Comment: okay, I understand the explanation. Maybe it would be beneficial to add this to your answer. Thanks again!

Comment: @Zorg Yes, at least, certainly will not be wrong... :) Did it.